# Third Isomorphism Theorem statement

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

If $H \vartriangleleft G$ and $K \vartriangleleft G$ then $K/H \vartriangleleft G/H$. Then : $(G/H) / (K/H)$ is isomorphic to $G/H$ .

I know this is the statement of the theorem but would it be correct to state the theorem as "If $H \vartriangleleft K \vartriangleleft G$...."?

Comment: You use $<$ between subgroups, which doesn't usually mean normal subgroup. There's a triangle symbol for that, but I don't know MathJax for it. Also the subgroups need not be proper in the theorem.

Comment: I know I just couldn't figure it out either. But is the second ide true? Can I state the theorem both ways? @coffeemath

Comment: $K$ normal in $G$ doesn't follow immediately from just $K$ normal in $H$ and $H$ normal in $G.$ Can you show that? [maybe there's a simple counterexample...]

Comment: FYI, the $\vartriangleleft$ symbol is written using "\vartriangleleft". Similarly, $\vartriangleright$ is produced using "\vartriangleright".

Comment: Thank you @JoeDub

Comment: @coffeemath okay I see. I'll try think about this and figure out a counter example

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255274/are-normal-subgroups-transitive

Comment: Also you may use \lhd

Answer (score 0):

When you write $H\vartriangleleft K \vartriangleleft G$, you say "$H$ is normal in $K$, and $K$ is normal in $G$". This does not imply that $H$ is normal in $G$.

As a quick counterexample, one can consider the dihedral group $D_8$. This has a (noncyclic) subgroup $K$ of order $4$, so it is normal in $D_8$ (since it has index 2). However, $K$ has a subgroup $H$ that is normal in $K$ but not normal in $D_8$.