# If $K<H\triangleleft G$, does it follow that $K\triangleleft G$?

Tags: group-theory

If $K<H\triangleleft G$, does it follow that $K\triangleleft G$?
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit confused/confusing (are you asking us to prove the title of your question/first statement, or verify your proof of the second statement?). However, you need "characteristic"; the first statement is incorrect as is the final one (in general, $K\lhd H\lhd G\not\Rightarrow K\lhd G$).

Comment: Also, you have not defined $\sigma_a$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255274/are-normal-subgroups-transitive

Comment: @user1729 I edited my question. I was looking to prove the statement in the title.. Apologies for the confusion